# Autocomplete Textbox loaded from an Access Database receiving error message while Debugging

Tags: database, vb.net, autocomplete, textbox

I am trying to create an autocomplete textbox that is loaded with suggestions from an access database. However when I try to run the application in debugging mode, it runs but no window pops up.

Also I am receiving this message in the Error List.

> A first chance exception of type System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Here is the code I am using, could someone please lend a helping hand?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Dim query As String
Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
                                  & Application.StartupPath & "\Drugs.accdb;")
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        con.Open()

        query = "SELECT * FROM Drug"


        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)


        Dim dt As New DataTable

        da.Fill(dt)


        Dim r As DataRow

        TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()

        Dim maxcolumn As Integer = dt.Columns.Count - 1

        For Each r In dt.Rows
            For i As Integer = 0 To maxcolumn

                TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(r.Item(i).ToString)
            Next i
        Next r
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    con.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please paste the whole Exception information

Comment: Hi there, what exactly do you mean by exception information? I'm new to programming is all.

Comment: The error you are receiving, there might be Additional Information avaialble to that

Comment: Ohh ok I see. Where would I find that? The error doesn't stop the program from running, it just says it in the Error List every time I run it in debugging mode. Thanks very much for wanting to help me :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20955027/how-to-catch-an-exception-and-show-its-details